# Including few subtotals in middle of a dataset?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have categories (row header) and each category has a sub category (gender), broken down by age range (column header). One of the categories can be divided into two sections and each of the sections would need a subtotal.

The dataset for the table would retrieves information from a MSSQL view which returns the category, gender, and age ranges (the count of each).

A method which worked so far but seem very inefficient is to create datasets (along with a tablix) for Category 1-2, 3AB, 3CD, 3Total, 4-5 and a total. Then align each tablix close to one another so when previewing the report, it would appear they all belong to one grid. I would like to explore other possibilities to achieve this outcome.

[Example in excel of how it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8298.png)

Thank you for reading

edit- Thank you Sean for pointing it out I need to be more clear. My actual question is how can I include a subtotal and total row in the middle of a dataset of certain categories, efficiently?

Comment: What is the actual question here? You seem to need help with something but it is not at all clear what you are trying to do. This might be a good place to start. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It sounds like you are taking one column (Category) and arbitrarily grouping specific values into a set to be subtotaled.  So, Categories 1,2,3a,3b,3c,3d,4, and 5 need to be aggregated as [1,2]; [3]; [3a,3b]; [3c,3d]; [4]; and [5].  Don't ask SSRS to do this for you.  Add a column to your dataset that defines these 'subsets' as unique groups.  Then you'll be able to get all this done in a single tablix.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like a simple [row/column grouping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/understanding-groups-report-builder-and-ssrs) tablix.

Modify your dataset to return "category, section, gender, age range, count" and then create a tablix with category->section->gender row groups and a single "age range" column group.  For those categories without a section, just return a sentinel string value of some sort, e.g. "All" or the category again.

If you aren't familiar with nested groups, start by adding gender, then section, then category (child to parent) as I find this the most intuitive way to teach people about adding groups.